# No TypeScript Build tab vs 2022

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, bundle

This question has come up before but everything I could find here is 5+ years old and the main solution didn't work for me. That being:

> 1. Add a `temp.ts` file and save it (in my case this is a solution that is in maintenance mode so I may never need to add new .ts files
>    for new features, etc., but to do so temporarily is trivial)
> 2. Open the MyProject right-click > Properties and save them
> 3. Close the solution (If you don't close the solution the *TypeScript Build* Tab doesn't seem to show)
> 4. Reopen Solution to see *TypeScript Build* Tab in the projects properties.
> 5. Delete the `temp.ts` file

Following the instructions above I still don't have that tab.

When I do add the ts file this piece of code, this gets added to my .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{4A0DDDB5-7A95-4FBF-97CC-616D07737A77}" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This remains even upon removing the .ts file.

Any suggestions?